# What means cmdand/cmdor in zsh?

Tags: zsh

Why does zsh print `cmdand` for every `&&` at the beginning of the line?

For instance when I paste the following lines into a Z shell

```
echo "foo" && echo "bar" && \
echo "buz" && \
echo "jam"
```

... zsh would display me the following

```
echo "foo" && echo "bar" && \
cmdand cmdand> echo "buz" && \
cmdand cmdand cmdand> echo "jam"
```

So zsh prepends a `cmdand` for every `&&` it encountered up to that line.
I just noticed that similar holds for `||` and `cmdor`.

Why would this be useful at all? Doesn't it just clutter the console? Can this behaviour be controlled?

I observed this behaviour on Mac OS and Ubuntu for zsh versions >5.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is controlled by the value of the environment variable `PS2`, whose default value `'%_> '` gives this behaviour. Its purpose is to show where you are in a multi-line command (and not just lines ending in back-slash), eg if you type a conditional command over several lines you will get:-

```
$ if [ "$var" ]
if> then
then> echo var: $var
then> else
else> echo var: not set
else> fi
var: not set
$
```

The shell does not distinguish between typed and pasted lines.

Set `PS2='> '` for a simple `>` on each continuation line.

For more information, see the manual `man zshall` and search for `PS2`.

Comment: To complete your answer, I'd like to add the purpose of this additional prompt: It's main purpose lies in the interactive use of the shell. Consider for example you start an _if_ clause like that `if [[ $foo == $(bar` and press enter, the PS2 prompt `[ if cond cmdsubst ]` reminds you, that there is an unfinished _if_, and unfinished _condition_ and an unfinished _command substitution_ you have to terminated correctly.

Comment: @AFH: Wow, many thanks. I was not aware of `PS2` or any other _prompt string_. I get the impression that this is not a zsh specific behaviour then, right? bash for instance also makes use of these `PS` variables.

Comment: @mpy - You're quite right: the questioner did ask why it would be useful. I have expanded my answer, as you have suggested.

Comment: @normanius - Yes, `bash` also has these variables, but it doesn't have the `%...` sequences, so lacks the facility to use `%_` in the prompt string to show where you are in a multi-line command. Korn shell has them, and Bourne shell has most of them, apart from `PS3`. Note that `%_` can be used in any of the `zsh` prompt strings, though it is not useful in the others.